# Как получить связи у коллекции пользователей

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть коллекция пользователей

```
$department = Department::find(1)->users;
```

Мне нужно получить к ним отношения Journal, ниже код рабочий, но тут используется условия на прямую из таблицы `Users`, а мне конкретно нужно из коллекции `$department`

```
User::where('name', '<>', 'Manager')
        ->with(['journal' => function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('schedule', 'like', "%" . $request->date . "%");
    }])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну если читать документацию по получению связующих таблиц, то есть способы как это делать.

1. Так же из бд, при получении коллекции. (`users` вызвать как метод `users()`)

   ```
   Department::find(1)->users()->with('journal')->get();
   ```
2. Если уж надо из коллекции, например такая ситуация возникает когда идёт в `blade` перебор массива через цикл и надо динамически получить под таблицы, то:

   ```
   $users = Department::find(1)->users;
   $users->load('journal');
   ...
   ```

Вы можете выводить просто на каждой итерации `$user->journal`, но тогда на каждый вызов будет запрос в бд, если у вас 100 пользователей, то это 100 запросов в бд.
Для этого и существует метод `load()`